# Running using axis2 inside a WAR application

Tags: apache-axis

I am trying to add Axis2 parsing/handling to my existing web application.  This compiles into a WAR file, however, my understanding (hopefully incorrect) of the Axis2 process is that to run it inside of a Tomcat server you need to install the Axis2.war servlet, and then compile the Axis2 application into an .aar file and place it in the $CATALINA_HOME/axis2/services subdirectory.

I need this to work compiled into a war file and put in a normal location.

From my understanding, to use Axis2 you need the servlet container to have a transport listener, which is the Axis2.war servlet.  This will then delegate to the relevant installed .aar file.  I have read a lot of the documentation and can't see how to make Axis2 more transparent.

Has anyone got any knowledge of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the axis2 as a servlet of your current application . 
All you have to do is add to your web.xml something like this:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
   <servlet-class>
      org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet
   </servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And a mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[Here](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3777111) is a guide for the configuration.